# error trying to capture a part from a string python

Tags: python, string, pexpect

im tring to capture a part from a string im giving it the location i want in integers but it keep telling me its tuple i don't know why
im using pexpect to get a version from network device

```
ssh_device.sendline('/info/sys/general')
ssh_device.expect('(?i)FLASH')
ver_long = ssh_device.before
print ver_long
print "\nthe ver_long type is "
print type(ver_long)
location = int(ver_long.find('('))
print "\nthe location type is "
print type(location)
print location
ver_short = ver_long[location-25,location]
print ver_short
```

the output is :

> System Information at  0:05:17 Sat Jan  3, 2070 Time zone:
>   America/US/Pacific Daylight Savings Time Status: Enabled
>
> BNT Layer 2/3 Copper Gigabit Ethernet Switch Module for IBM
>   BladeCenter
>
> Switch has been up for 2 days, 8 hours, 5 minutes and 17 seconds. Last
>   boot: (reset from Telnet/SSH)
>
> MAC Address: 00:22:00:63:4a:00    Management IP Address (if 128):
>   10.106.12.25 Software Version 5.2.3.1 (
>
> the ver_long type is  'str'
>
> the location type is  'int' 294 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "version.py", line 83, in 
>       ver_short = ver_long[location-25,location] TypeError: string indices must be >integers, not tuple

notice that the type is int !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a colon, not a comma to define the start and end of a slice:

```
ver_short = ver_long[location-25:location]
```

Comment: im felling so stupid right now.....

Comment: It happens...:) specially when you switch between languages.